# How to display updated content of a file?

Tags: python

I have a json file, which gets updated once in a week. I want a python script which will show only the updated data on the terminal.

```
with open("test.json") as jsonFile:
    data = json.load(jsonFile)
```

this code reads the data and shows the entire content but i want to show only the updated ones.

json file:

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Russo Hoover"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Stout Fry"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "George Whale"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Jenny"
  }
]
```

Comment: How can you identify the updated records?

Comment: Do you have backup of old json file?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to keep the old version (rename it `whatever.json.old`, for instance) and just compare the two once it gets updated.

Essentially:

```
if(oldRecord != newRecord)
    show(newRecord)

if(!oldRecords.contains(newRecord))
    show(newRecord)
```

Sorry for the bad pseudocode.

Once you did that you can overwrite the old version with the new one if you don't need it any longer.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a "newlyUpdated": "true/false" pair to the objects

or

Save the old list somewhere and do a comparison, showing only those entries not present in the old one

or

Have a updatesList that you show and then empty each week.